# SPARQL - Query all things

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to find all DBpedia resources with rdf:type equal to owl:Thing. How can I extract such a list using SPARQL? What query would I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a triple would be something like
`:a rdf:type owl:Thing` and SPARQL is using triple patterns to match triples, you need a variable at the positions of the triple which is not fixed:

```sql
SELECT * WHERE {
 ?s a <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>
}
```